# Get data from firestore and convert to json and use that in factory constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, factory

I am using a `firestore` as database. If the data not present in database then it will do `webscrape`. In `webscrape` I managed to convert the data into `json` and used `factory constructor`. I want the same thing should happen while fetching data from `firestore`.

One More thing I have a **specific collection** and **document id** So I used `.collection('medicine').doc('id').get()`.

##### Factory Constructor

```
class Tablet {
  String name;
  String introduction;
  Tablet({
    this.name,
    this.introduction,
  });
  factory Tablet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Tablet(
      name: json['name'],
      introduction: json['introduction'],
    );
  }
}
```

##### Method which get Data from Database If Data Present

This is a Method which must returns `Future<Tablet>` (I stuck in `if condition`)

```
  Future<Tablet> details;
  Future<Tablet> getDetails(String medName) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('medicine')
        .doc(medName.toLowerCase())
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot) {
      if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        var json = jsonDecode(docSnapshot.data().toString());  // I am getting stuck here
        details = Tablet.fromJson(json) as Future<Tablet>;
      } else {
        print('Data not present in Database..');
        details = webScrape(medName);
      }
    });
    return details;
  }
```

What I Tried in `webscrape(medName)` is

```
Tablet.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
```

Here returning above line and assigning it to Future works but in the `if` condition, It is asking for type cast and the following error thrown

##### Error

```
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
{benefits: {values: [{header: In Heartburn, display_text: Heartburn and aci...
 ^
```

---

#### Update

As @Tarik Huber 2nd suggestion, Inspired and changed a code little bit as shown

```
factory Tablet.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot docSnap){
  return Tablet(
    name: docSnap.get('name');
    introduction: docSnap.get('introduction');
  );
}
```

Now My Question is, the below code isn't working

```
details = Tablet.fromSnapshot(docSnapshot.data()) as Future<Tablet>  // is not working
```

instead calling async function did as shown

```
details = arrangeData(docSnapshot.data());
Future<Tablet> arrangeData(DocumentSnapshot data) async{
  return Tablet.fromSnapshot(data);
}
```

I know It's not a good approach and It is working but don't know How? Can anyone Explain..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it with:

```
details = Tablet.fromJson(docSnapshot.data()) as Tablet;
```

the data is of type `Map<String,dynamic>`. That is the same type your convertion functions takes.

Othervise you could just add a

```
  factory Tablet.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot) {
    return Tablet(
      name: docSnapshot.get('name'),
      introduction: docSnapshot.get('introduction'),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I tried the first one earlier, which results `type 'Tablet' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Tablet>' in type cast`. Now I am trying the second which says `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.` while creating `factory constructor`

Comment: Okay Thx for your 2nd approach and sorry for large comment. It shows an error as I mentioned in the above comment but I changed a little bit like `docSnapshot.get('name')` instead of yours and again it says `type 'Tablet' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Tablet>' in type cast` So Simply I created a **async** method of return type `Future<Tablet>` and called `Tablet.fromDocumentSnapshot(docSnapshot)`. Now It works but too many unsolved questions .Why it happens can anyone explain it? In Simple why `typecast` doesn't work but calling a `async method` works both doing same things

Comment: Can you pls share your latest code in an update part of your question.

Comment: Why do you use `Future<Tablet>`? Can you try it with: `details = Tablet.fromSnapshot(docSnapshot.data()) as Tablet ` ?

Comment: I am sending `Future<Tablet>` details to a `future builder` present in another page which extracts all data and displays the information and since I am using `webscrap` technology when data is not present in database so it return `Future` only.

Comment: Just to explain the `why`: `Future<Tablet>` is not the same as just `Tablet`. The first one represents async code and the second one syncronous code. If you need the Future one you get it as you shown it in your update by adding an `async` call to your code. That will change `Tablet` to `Future<Tablet>`

Comment: Okay Thanks!!. Can I have any other option apart from calling `async` function to convert `Tablet` to `Future<Tablet>`?  Just curious..

Comment: Update your answer to `.get()` because `.data()[]` gives error as `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.`

Comment: Thx. I have update the answer. Actualy that is the easiest syntax to do it. You could refactor `Tablet.fromSnapshot` to return a Future but I would leave it in case you sometimes don't need one in other parts of the app.

Comment: Okay Thx for your time. A much appreciated.